# How do I change the default location for Git Bash on Windows?

Tags: git, windows-7, git-bash

I am using Git on Windows 7 and access my repositories through Git Bash. How can I change the default location that Git Bash opens in a convenient folder when I start it?

It's somewhat time consuming to navigate to `htdocs`, and then a specific folder. Is there a way to change the configuration file to have it open elsewhere? Or would it be possible to write a `.sh` file to do this?

Unfortunately Git Bash won't open my `htdocs` folder shortcut on my desktop, and it takes using `cd` 5 times to get to my desired directory.

Comment: Related: [How to change folder with git bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8961334/3357935)

Answer (score 251, accepted):

After installing msysgit I have the `Git Bash here` option in the context menu in Windows Explorer. So I just simply navigate to the directory and then open Bash right there.

I also copied the default `Git Bash` shortcut to the desktop and edited its `Start in` property to point to my project directory. It works flawlessly.

Windows 7x64, msysgit.

Comment: I think the `Start in` part is what he's most interested in - if you're using the windows shell (`cmd.exe`), you can also turn on `QuickEdit mode` through the same properties dialog to make copy/paste a *bit* easier and set the window size/buffer/font properties and such...

Comment: I don't have this `Git Bash Here` option. How do I do it then?

Comment: @ptamzz "I also copied default Git Bash shortcut to desktop and edited its Start in property to point to my project directory."

Comment: To get to `Git Bash`'s `Start in` property, Right-Click your Git Bask shortcut icon and click "Properties". Then find and paste in the `Start in` field the path you'd like to start in. It will look something like: `C:\Users\DM\Desktop\YourFolder`

Comment: I went the way Mikeumus says editing the start in property. I then started gitbash and pinned it in taskbar. It now opens to the desired location from the taskbar too.

Comment: @Mikeumus `Start In` Doesn't seem to do it for me, it keeps starting in `users/user` am i missing something else here?

Comment: Right `cd-to-home` was overriding my `start in` value. all sorted now.

Comment: For `Start in` value, I use `%USERPROFILE%/Git` where `Git` is a directory under my home directory e.g. `C:\users\rami\Git`

Comment: One thing that has been skipped in this answer is that you should remove the `--cd-to-home` part at the end of `Target` field value.

Comment: will this work if my directory not from C:\ but from D:\   Do I need to restart system after changing the startIn path, I have removed --cd-to-home from target but still not opening git bash from my path

Comment: Every time you update `Git Bash` a new shortcut will be automatically created and you have to repeat this process from scratch. To avoid this, see `@smilyface`'s answer.

Comment: Yes, it works, but ONLY if you remove `--cd-to-home` like mentioned in the solution below which should get way more credit for that important hint in my opinion...

Answer (score 281):

The easiest way without installing msysgit is right click on the Git Bash shortcut icon → *Start in:* → "C:\Program Files (x86)".

Change the *Start in* entry and point out the Git Bash starting position. If you don't remove the `--cd-to-home` part from the Target box, the Start in change gets overridden.

**Alternate Option:**

If you don't have the shortcut and installed in the default location, open up a file explorer and paste in the search path field:

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Git`

That will take you to the Git shortcuts location

- Right click on 'Git Bash'
- Click 'Properties'
- Navigate to 'Shortcut' pivot
- As others have said, in Target remove: `--cd-to-home`
- Update **Start in** row to **C:\Program Files (x86)** or for me it was

  - **C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\Sites**
- Apply as Administrator

Good to go

Comment: I found yours and Marcin's solution were the same, but for me, your instructions were more precise and to the point. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip to remove the `--cd-to-home` argument.

Comment: @ShirishHerwade I had to unpin from taskbar and pin it again to make it work.

Comment: Still the most helpful solution in 2020

Comment: "Change the Start in entry and point out the Git Bash starting position." What does that mean? Can someone provide an example value to use?

Comment: The accepted answer should have an edit to remove that --cd-to-home from the target part.

Comment: this did not work for me in the pinned git bash unless, only when the result was from a Windows search for git bash. I tried to unpin and pin it again and it was still not working. I needed to use the .bashrc solution below.

Answer (score 190):

Add this line to your `.bashrc` file:

```
cd C:/xampp/htdocs/<name of your project>;
```

If the .bashrc file doesn't exist, create one in your root folder. For me it is: `C:\Users\tapas\`

Save .bashrc and open Git Bash. That's it!

Comment: This is the correct answer! And if `.bashrc` was not there, just create it in `~` (cd ~ && touch .bashrc)

Comment: This `.bashrc` approach is a handy solution if you want to put the console into `/c/whatever` and can't put `/c/whatever` into the `Start in` properties setting as other answers suggested. The `/c/whatever` path only seems to work in newer versions of gitbash.

Comment: I found `bash.bashrc` in `Git\etc` folder

Comment: I found this solution good but it doesn't play well with custom shortcuts or the `Git Bash here` options described by other answers. I solved it by adding a conditional so it only runs when in the home folder. `if [[ $(pwd) = $HOME ]]; then cd <location> fi`

Comment: Thanks @Forss! That wrapper is a crazy good idea.  Don't forget the semicolon after the location!

Comment: Thanks @peter-mortensen &soundswaste, helped me tremendously. I just added the that line at the very end of the brashrc file, worked great!

Comment: Note: You may need to use vi in Git Bash itself to create the file, Windows was getting annoyed that I tried to rename a file with no "name", just an "extension"

Comment: Forss's tip is great, but has a syntax error, as pointed out by @Travis Watson. It should be `if [[ $(pwd) = $HOME ]]; then cd <location>; fi`

Comment: Good solution but if you're using Git Bash as terminal for VS Code now when opening terminal in VS code it wont default to the project's repo anymore

Comment: this was the cleanest solution

Comment: In windows, I had to add this in ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 30):

I read it somewhere and it worked for me.

First check in git bash what is the HOME location. Open git bash and run

```
echo $HOME
```

Now change the HOME path by opening cmd and run

```
setx HOME "path/to/.ssh/loc" (I gave C:\Users\aXXXX)
```

Now cross check by running the echo command in git bash.

Comment: I think this is a very good answer, especially if your company has a network mapped home directory which you do *not* want to use (ie. for performance reasons)

Comment: will this HOME path changing will affect only git bash or total system command prompt?

Comment: Excellent solution, fixed a severe slowness I had with Git Bash with my P: drive on a slow remote drive over VPN. I find it strange, however, how I can use this solution for `HOME` but not for `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` - I cannot change where `cmd` launches with this solution. But no matter, Git Bash is what was affected and it's now working properly again.

Comment: Note that this solution also changes where Git Bash looks for your dotfiles, which solved my problem, but might not be the right solution for other situations, and probably would not have been what OP wanted.

Comment: This solution broke Git-Bash for me, I can no longer open the program

Comment: You might have to specify the new path as `"/c/YourNewFolder/"` instead of `"C:\YourNewFolder"`

Answer (score 26):

Windows 10 tested solution

- Type git bash in **search**
- Right click on it and choose **open file location**
- Right click on it and choose **properties**
- At **target** remove **--cd-to-home** from "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd-to-home
- At **start in** put the path of the directory you want it to start at
  for example Start in: C:\xampp\htdocs

Comment: **I did this but still same as previous, will this work if start in was in the local disk D:\ any info.**

Answer (score 24):

Open the properties of the bash and change to "Start in" to where you want to start in. After this, (I had this problem and I solved it by doing this) go to target and delete the --cd-to-home parameter part after "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" . Only THEN will you start in the "Start in" directory that you specified.

Comment: Vladimir, deleting the --cd-to-home parameter part after "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" is an important detail. Thanks.

Comment: Alert!..life saver :)

Answer (score 18):

If you're like me, and the way you get to Git is <kbd>windows key</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then you can simply hit the <kbd>windows key</kbd>, search for Git, right click on the resulting `Git Bash` icon, select properties, and change the `Start in:` field.

I'm not exactly sure what this does, because I'm not exactly sure what Git on Windows is (a facade on top of sh which itself is a facade on cmd?), but in any case, you can now pin the shortcut that Windows pulls up on a search for "Git" to your taskbar, or to your desktop, and it will still start in whatever directory you set it to.

Comment: So that is why it did't work. I forgot to update the pinned shortcut in my taskbar. Your "now pin (...)" did ring the bell :)

Answer (score 13):

1/ Go to **Properties** of Git Bash

2/ Change **Start in:** to your the directory of your choi

3/ Delete **`--cd-to-home`**

[image]

4/ Restart Git Bash

Answer (score 10):

Right click on `Git Bash shortcut`and then go to `properties`.
In `properties` inside `start in` option add the location of the directory you want to start `Git Bash` in and `apply` the changes.

Answer (score 9):

I am using Git bash on Windows 10, here is my solution:

1. Close all git bash sessions
2. Hit windows key and type: `env`; then click `Edit environment variables for your account` (control panel)
3. Under "User variables for ...."; hit `New` button
4. Variable Name: HOME
5. Variable value: path where you would like `~/` to be in git bash

Open a git bash session and test it by typing: `pwd` and double check by doing `cd ~/ && pwd`

Comment: Some versions of Git use HOMEPATH instead of HOME.  If you check the start in folder for Git Bash you can see which environment variable is used.

Answer (score 9):

Git bash is used to play with bash commands. So I **use bash method** itself in windows `Git bash`

Edit your `.bash_profile` (create it if you doesnot have one - see below how to create). Enter the following lines.

#### Add these lines to the file

```
alias ws="cd /d/workspace/"
ws
```

#### My .bash_profile looks like this

```
Smilyface@SmilingMachine /d/workspace
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
alias ws="cd /d/workspace/"
ws
```

#### How to create a new .bash_profile ?

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
```

OR write into the file directly

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Simple, aha !

Comment: precise and clear, of course ~/.bashrc file would be okay too.

Answer (score 6):

Once you have updated the `Start in:` field make sure to remove the `--cd-to-home` at the end of the `Target:` field

Answer (score 6):

**If using Windows OS then add target like above** :

1. Right click on git terminal > Properties

[image: Step > one]

2. Properties>Under shortcut tab>Start in:
   add your folder target path like below image

[image: Step > two]

Answer (score 5):

Make a Git Bash shortcut to Desktop for convenience then right click on the icon goto properties. Here you will find the *Start in:* section with a text box. Replace the path you want, for example like:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Desktop
```

Then open it directly by clicking on the icon. You will get the default Desktop path in Git Bash.

Comment: Ah! I also needed to remove the `--cd-to-home` option.

Answer (score 5):

Open this file:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\etc\bash.bashrc
```

And append the following line:

```
cd /c/Users/<User>/Documents/path/to/your/repos
```

Restart Git bash

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Git Bash through Windows Terminal, you can set the starting directory (of any profile).

In Windows Terminal, go to `Settings` > `Open JSON file`.
In this file, in `profiles` > `list`, you can set the `startingDirectory` property (backslashes need to be escaped).

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-general#starting-directory).

[image: open settings screenshot]

[image: JSON files screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

I liked Peter Mortenson's answer, but I would like to expand.

'cd ~' in the .bashrc file causes the "Git Bash Here" feature of Git Bash to stop working.  Instead, add this if statement to the .bashrc file:

```
if [ "$PWD" == '/' ]
then
        cd ~
fi
```

This will change to the home directory when Git Bash is run on its own, but when "Git Bash Here" is run, the current working directory will not be changed.

Comment: I like this idea but it doesn't actually work as written because $PWD contains '/c/Users/<my name>/', not '/'. Git bash starts in ~. I don't see Peter's answer though, so maybe I'm basing this on a totally different solution.

Answer (score 3):

the only way that worked for me on windows 10:

1. right-click gitbash shortcut -> proporties
2. change target as: "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd=C:\Users\test\Desktop\

This will always open desktop path

Answer (score 3):

Add a line to change to the desired directory in your .bashrc file or create a .bashrc if you don't have one.

I.e. add `cd C:/path/to/yourfolder` to your .bashrc file

Be mindful that the path format is forward slash '/' Unix style and not Windows '\' backslash.

One way to do this is to open bash and edit it using vim

1. Open up Git Bash
2. Run vim ~/.bashrc
3. Press i in order to insert characters
4. Type cd C:/path/to/folder; (make sure you use forward slashes)
5. Press esc to exit the insert mode
6. Press :wq or ZZ to save and exit vim

I found this solution on https://simplernerd.com/cli-git-bash-default/

Answer (score 2):

Just type the path of your local directory (Git project home directory) in the properties of Git Bash. I.e. set path C:\yourprojsctdirectory to Git Bash's properties field "Execute In" or (Ausführen in). That's it!

Now double click Git Bash. The Git header will be on your "yourprojsctdirectory".

Answer (score 2):

The working solution listed are great, but the problem occurs when you want **multiple default home** for your git-bash.

A simple workaround is to start **git-bash** using **bat** script.

#### git-bash-to-htdocs.bat

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs
"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"
```

The above of course assume git-bash is installed at `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe`

You can create multiple `.bat` file so your git-bash can start where it want to be

Answer (score 1):

Add  "cd your_repos_path" to your Git profile, which is under the `%`.

Answer (score 1):

As from [this link](https://codetryout.com/how-to-set-git-bash-home-directory/)

lets say you want your change to default location to c:\myprojects

Open git bash

type in:

echo "cd 'C:\myprojects'" >> ~/.bash_profile

Press Enter

Close Git bash and open again

You should start from c:\myprojects

Tested on git version 2.36.1 on windows

Troubleshoot:

1. Make sure you type in the folder inside the '' and the entire cd command inside "" just like the example
2. make sure folder exist

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following; it helped me. I hope it help you also.

```
cd /c/xampp/your-project
```

Comment: @MuhammadSohailiqbal - The question is how to set it in default. So that whenever he opens the Git Bash, it should directly go to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using git-bash inside of vscode as a terminal I don't always want to cd into a specific directory, for this to work I checked if my current directory(`pwd`) is `/` and if so it should only then cd to `~`. So whenever I open the terminal inside vscode git-bash's current working directory is my opened folder inside of vscode and it doesn't change to `~` since it only does that when my current working directory is `/`.

For this to work I added following if condition into `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
if [ $(pwd) = '/' ] then cd ~; fi
```

**TIP**: make sure your `~/.bash_profile` actually loads `~/.bashrc` by a line like the following:

```sh
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .bashrc configuration file:

```
cd ~ && touch .bashrc && echo "cd /folder1/folder2/folder3"
```

Change cd command to the directory you want.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11, create a file named `.bashrc`  in your user directory, like `C:/user/.bashrc`, and add this single line to the file:
`cd ~ [enter the full path of where you want git bash to start up]`.
It took a while, but I found out that `~` is the 'wildcard' option, so you could type something specific like `cd ~/MyProject` and always start there.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 11 if you pined gitbash to TaskBar then it loosing "--cd-to-home" flag. So it has to be added there manually again. It can be done via right click on the pinned icon and then again right click on gitbash icon. Then "properties".