# How to change folder with git bash?

Tags: git, git-bash

My default `git` folder is `C:\Users\username\.git`.

What command should I use to go into `C:/project`?

Answer (score 606, accepted):

The command is:

```
cd  /c/project/
```

**Tip:**
Use the `pwd` command to see which path you are currently in, handy when you did a right-click "Git Bash here..."

Comment: Is there a way to save long directories? I know `cd $USER` will bring me to my users directory on windows.

Comment: @reubenjohn, using Console2 for console provides a setting "Startup dir". Btw this [article](http://happypolla.blogspot.com/2013/03/guake-like-bash-terminal-for-windows-7.html) describes to make the console Quake-style dropping down form top of the screen.

Comment: If there are any spaces in the path then you need quotes. eg: `cd "/c/program files (x86)/git/bin/"`

Comment: I hate to ask if it's obvious; but would this same command work if my pwd told me I was currently in the F: drive?

Comment: @the-red-pea Paths starting with a `/` such as `/c/project/` are absolute paths and always work regardless of your current path.  when the path doesn't start with a forward-slash (relative paths) sush as `cd project` it will try to go that subdirectory based on your current-working-directory (pwd)

Comment: Thanks @BobFanger ; so I can effectively "change drives" (if that's the right word) like `cd /f/folder` and `cd /c/folder` I ask because in Windows command/console, you must change drives like `F:` or `C:`, even though it seems like you can cd too.

Comment: I prefer
  `you@yourWorkStation MINGW64 /       cd c && ls`
     to let the user choose the good directory 
 CD : for change directory 
 && : to chain your command 
 ls : for list

Answer (score 98):

Go to the directory manually and do right click → Select 'Git bash' option.

Git bash terminal automatically opens with the intended directory. For example, go to your project folder. While in the folder, right click and select the option and 'Git bash'. It will open automatically with `/c/project`.

Comment: This is an awful advice, promoting "console illiteracy". Also it **doesn't answer** the question. The OP wants to change directory from within git bash, not to reopen a new git bash in a folder. And it's also **useless for scripting**, as it's not possible to "go to folder and right click" in a script.

Comment: Not awful, but I would call it evil.

Answer (score 50):

Here are the steps I followed:

1. In bash, check in which directory you are by using the command:

   ```
   $ pwd
   ```
2. copy the URL of the directory you want to go like after using the first command (`PWD`) I got:

   ```
   $  /c/Users/yourUsername
   ```
3. Now I want to change this to the directory of `c` drive and folder `MyPictures`. To do that, I will go the directory of `MyPictures`, copy the URL,
   and paste it in the Git bash. However, before that:

   > [image: syntax changes in bash]

   `C:\MyPicture` becomes `$ cd /C/MyPicture` (backslashes are replaced with slashes)
4. if the folder name is having some spaces like (my program) then you need to enclose it in double quotes like:

   ```
   $ cd "C:\Program Files"
   ```
5. Remember to change directory you just need to copy the `requiredUrl` and paste that in bash with double-quotes like:

   ```
   cd "required URL"
   ```

**Note:** URL required with slashes.

Comment: Simple and easy Answer. 
The corrected command, in step no.4 is  `$ cd/ c/"Program Files"`

Answer (score 31):

## How to change folders in Git Bash

As [Bob mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8961349/3357935), you can change directories with [`cd`](https://ss64.com/bash/cd.html):

```
cd /c/project
```

If you have a Windows path with backslashes or spaces, enclose the path in double quotes:

```
cd "C:\project"
```

#### Tips

- You can check the current folder with `pwd`.
- If the path contains spaces, you will need to use quotation marks. (`cd "C:/Program Files"`)
- On Windows, you change the default starting directory for Git Bash.

  - Right click `git-bash.exe`, select *Properties*, open *Shortcuts*, and change *Start in:* to your most commonly used folder. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kZ0c.png))
- The `cd` command can be memorized as "*change directory*".

#### See also

- ss64 - [Bash CD command](https://ss64.com/bash/cd.html)
- Stack Overflow - [Forward slash vs backward slash for file path in git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40396613/3357935)

Comment: Thanks a lot! the command cd "C:\project" saved my time hugely :)

Answer (score 17):

`pwd`: to check where you are (If necessary)

`cd`: change directory

In your case if I understand you, you need:

```
cd c/project
```

Answer (score 13):

## Your Question is :

My default git folder is C:\Users\username.git

But I want to go into c:/project

## What command do I need to get into that?

Since you have asked primarily about gitbash which is Linux based (Terminal), there are differences in commands when compared with Command Prompt of Windows.
We'll discuss gitbash (Terminal) commands only.

1.First of all we must understand that command line(In Windows) and Terminal(In Mac) always points to some folder on storage Drives .

**To check towards what directory it is pointing to at any given time.** You need to type the command: **pwd** "an acronym for 'Print Working Directory' ".

[image: pwd command in Linux]

2. There is a command **ls** which gives us information about the folders and files in a particular directory. This is quite a handy command and often used to know about the file structure. In my answer I will make use of this also.

[image]

3. To traverse along the folder tree we make use of yet another very important command know as **cd** which stands for change directory. And your question has the answer within this **cd** command only.

Here are some of the ways to traverse along the folder tree:

3a) **cd**  command let's us traverse to child directory. Kindly check the snapshot.
[image: Going to child directory]

3b) Now to traverse back into the parent directory, we make use of **cd ..** command: Please check the Image below:
[image]

**By Using the above two steps we can easily solve your Query:**

A) Currently you are in  : C:\Users\username.git

So, doing **cd ..** will point the Terminal towards **Users** folder.

[image]

B) Again Typing cd .. will make Terminal to point towards C Drive.

[image]

C) Now doing **ls** at this point will let you know about all the folders and files in C drive.

Check if there is a **project** folder, Then simply for the last time type the command:

**cd project**

And Walla you are have traveled so far to reach to your destination. Congratulations.

[image]

**Note:** If the **project** folder is not created with C drive, simply write the command **mkdir project** and it will be created. Then follow the above steps to play around.

**4) There is one more straight forward quick solution to your problem in particular:**

Wherever the terminal is pointing.
Simply write the command:

4a) **cd /** It will point to default root folder.

Then type the command : **cd /c/** to point towards c directory.
   Then simply go to child directory, which in your case is **project** directory 
   by typing:

**cd project**

[image]

And you are good to go: ENJOY :)

Comment: Thanks. To navigate one folder back, just cd ..

Answer (score 6):

From my perspective, the fastest way to achieve what you're looking for is to change "***Start in***" value.

To do that, right-click on `git-bash.exe`, go to *Properties* and change *Start In* value to the folder you want.

Answer (score 4):

Right clicking a specific folder can help ease your pain than just by typing the whole directory. Right click + clicking s or Right click and then click "GIT bash here"

Hope this seems helpful

Answer (score 4):

Simply type `cd` then copy and paste the file path.

Example of changing directory:

[image: example of changing directory]

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add that if you are using a shared drive, enclose the path in double quotes and keep the backslashes. This is what worked for me:

```
$cd /path/to/"\\\share\users\username\My Documents\mydirectory\"
```

Answer (score 1):

For the fastest way
**$ cd "project"**

Answer (score 1):

cd c:/Users/username/Folder/SubFolder

Answer (score 0):

just right click on the desired folder and select git-bash Here option it will direct you to that folder and start working hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

To move from c drive to other drive(D or E)use this command----->

cd "your path"
Now hit enter. Check your path using $pwd.
Your path has been change from one directory to other.

Ex---> cd "D:\WEB_DEV\HTML_CSS_projects\TouristVisitors_LandingPage".
note - this is my path, your path should be different.

Answer (score -2):

if you are on windows then you can do a right click from the folder where you want to use git bash and select "GIT BASH HERE".
[image]