# Forward slash vs backward slash for file path in git bash

Tags: git, bash, directory, command

I am running these two commands in **Git bash**.

Why they behave differently? Aren't they supposed to do the same thing or am I missing something?

```
git diff > D:\Patches\afterWGComment.txt
```

creates file `PatchesafterWGComment.txt` in `D:/`

```
git diff > D:/Patches/afterWGComment.txt
```

correctly creates file `afterWGComment.txt` in `D:/Patches/`

Note that `D:/Patches/` folder is present before running the above commands.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Bash treats backslash as an escape character, meaning that the symbol following it is interpreted literally, and the backslash itself is dropped.

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/user
$ echo \$HOME
$HOME
```

Under Windows, where backslash serves as a path separator, this causes some inconvenience. Fortunately, inside single quotes a backslash character loses its special meaning and is treated literally (as any other character, except a single quote):

```
$ echo '\$HOME'
\$HOME
```

Therefore, if you are going to copy&paste a Windows path into Git bash, put it inside single quotes:

```
git diff > 'D:\Patches\afterWGComment.txt'
```

Comment: Is it safe if I use double quotes instead of single? I usually consider them same.

Comment: @SauravSahu No, backslash still acts as an escape character inside double quotes

Comment: "some inconvenience" is an understatement. You can't tab-expand quoted paths etc.

Comment: Beware that to escape backslash "\" you need another backslash "\\".

Answer (score 5):

Backslash is an escape character used to escape meta characters. This means you need to escape the escape:

```
D:\\Patches\\afterWGComment.txt
```

Alternative you can put your string in single quotes, which will make all characters literal:

```
'D\Patches\afterWGComment.txt'
```

Some meta characters: `*`, `~`, `$`, `!`, ...

Answer (score 2):

Well the `Backslash (\)` in Linux generally means a `escape character`. So in your case the backslash is escaping strings. Try with a `cd "D:\Patches\afterWGComment.txt"` and you can see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The back slash has a very long history in Unix (and therefore in Linux) of meanning: quote next character.

There are three ways to quote in the shell (where you type commands):

- The backquote (`\`)
- Single quotes (`'`)
- Double quotes (`"`)

In the order from stronger to softer. For example, a `$` is an special character in the shell, this will print the value of a variable:

```
$ a=Hello
$ echo $a
Hello
```

But this will not:

```
$ echo \$a
$a

$ echo '$a'
$a

$ echo "$a"
Hello
```

In most cases, a backslash will make the next character "not special", and usually will convert to the same character:

```
$ echo \a
a
```

Windows decided to use `\` to mean as the same as the character `/` means in Unix file paths.
To write a path in any Unix like shell with backslashes, you need to quote them:

```
$ echo \\
\
$ echo '\'
\
$ echo "\\"
\
```

For the example you present, just quote the path:

```
$ echo "Hello" > D:\\Patches\\afterWGComment.txt
```

That will create the file `afterWGComment.txt` that contains the word `Hello`.

Or:

```
$ echo "Hello" > 'D:\Patches\afterWGComment.txt'
$ echo "Hello" > "D:\\Patches\\afterWGComment.txt"
$ echo "Hello" > "D:/Patches/afterWGComment.txt"
```

Quoting is not simple, it has adquired a long list of details since the 1660's.