# git BASH: why is $HOME concatenation of path?

Tags: bash, git, ssh, git-clone

Some context: trying to clone a repo with ssh url from git BASH, but getting the following error:

```
Could not create directory '/c/Usersusername/.ssh'
The authenticity of host '...' can't be established.
```

Why are the Users and username subdirectories getting concatenated? Is this expected? I'm assuming this is causing the error and the failed clone request.

From git BASH:

```
$ echo $HOME
/c/Usersusername
```

From Windows cmd:

```
C:\ echo %HOME%
C:/Users/username
```

I've tried `$ setx home "C:/Users/username"` .

Comment: Looks like the forward and back slashes are interpreted differently by BASH, with the later being an escape character. The difference is further complicated by the use of single or double quotes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396613/forward-slash-vs-backward-slash-for-file-path-in-git-bash

Comment: `echo $HOME` can be misleading for any of [several reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else). What does `printf "'%s'\n" "$HOME"` show?

Answer (score 0):

Try and *not* set `HOME`: by default, git bash should use `%USERPROFILE%`

Try also to create in advance the `.ssh` folder, before using your SSH URL for cloning: that way, Git should directly go to the Host verification step, without failing on that folder creation.

Note: On Windows 10, with Git 2.32 for Windows, I do have a `HOME` set using `C:\...` backslash path, and it is correctly displayed as /c/... in a bash session without me setting it in `.bashrc` or `.profile`.