# Using Git over OpenSSH to deploy repo on windows server 2016

Tags: git, winapi, openssh

I am having difficulties to use git command from a bare repo located on an Ubuntu server to another bare repo located on a Windows server 2016 (within a Active Directory)

I am using https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH on the windows server to allow ssh connections in.

my .ssh/config

```
Host INTRANET
Hostname 192.168.1.153 
User git@INTRANET  
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Allow me to log in whith my rsa key

```
$ ssh INTRANET
```

Open a console where:

```
$ whoami
INTRANET+git
```

And

```
$ pwd
/c/Users/git
```

then

```
$ ls
 myrepo.git
```

And finally:

```
$ ls -all myrepo.git/
total 25
drwxr-xr-x 1 INTRANET+git 197121   0 Mar 27 13:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 INTRANET+git 197121   0 Mar 27 15:52 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 INTRANET+git 197121  60 Mar 23 11:46 FETCH_HEAD
-rw-r--r-- 1 INTRANET+git 197121  23 Mar 16 11:31 HEAD
-rw-r--r-- 1 INTRANET+git 197121 151 Mar 16 11:30 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 INTRANET+git 197121  73 Mar 16 11:30 description
drwxr-xr-x 1 INTRANET+git 197121   0 Mar 27 13:24 hooks
drwxr-xr-x 1 INTRANET+git 197121   0 Mar 27 13:24 info
drwxr-xr-x 1 INTRANET+git 197121   0 Mar 27 13:24 objects
-rw-r--r-- 1 INTRANET+git 197121 284 Mar 16 11:31 packed-refs
drwxr-xr-x 1 INTRANET+git 197121   0 Mar 27 13:24 refs
```

Ubuntu is holding a bare repo where

```
$ cat config
[remote "origin"]
    url = INTRANET:~/myrepo.git
```

But when I

```
$ git --bare fetch
fatal: ''~/myrepo.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: What's the path of your repo on the Windows server? Your first `ls` shows `myrepo.git`, but the second shows 'TREQ.git`.

Comment: @stephenNewell typo corrected

Answer (score 0):

Try instead using the full path

```
url = INTRANET:/c/Users/git/myrepo.git
```

That way, `~` does not have to be interpreted.

Comment: You mean  INTRANET:/c/Users/git/myrepo.git?

Comment: I still receive the same `fatal: ''/c/Users/git/myrepo.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: @PeterPeterson When you do a `ssh INTRANET`, can you go and `cd /c/Users/git/myrepo.git`, and do a `git status` in it, just to confirm the repo exists?

Comment: `ssh INTRANET` then `cd /c/Users/git/myrepo.git`. Since it's a bare repo a `git branch` give me `*master`

Comment: @PeterPeterson Can you change the User fro git@INTRANET to git in your ssh config?

Comment: I did try with no changes. `ssh git@192.168.1.xxx` is letting me in. But  `git --bare fetch ssh://git@192.168.1.xxx/c/Users/git/myrepo.git master` still give me 
`fatal: ''/c/Users/git/myrepo.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists`

Comment: @PeterPeterson I suppose `git ls-remote ssh://git@192.168.1.xxx/c/Users/git/myrepo.git` does not work either?

Comment: sameish. frustration here.

Comment: @PeterPeterson Check your `env|grep -i ssh` in case anything could influence an SSH connection.

Comment: server side (win2016) `$ env|grep -i ssh`
`SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.21 59606 192.168.1.153 22
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.21 59606 22
PLINK_PROTOCOL=ssh
PATH=/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/git/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/
c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/wamp/bin/php/ph
p5.5.12:/c/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext:/c/Program Files/Firebird/Firebird_2_5:/c/Progr
am Files/OpenSSH/bin:/cmd:/usr/bin:/mingw64/bin:/c/Windows/system32/config/systemprof
ile/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/git/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsA
pps
`

Comment: client side (ubuntu) `$ env|grep -i ssh`
`SSH_AGENT_PID=5270
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.33 53166 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-xz7DMENLb9jD/agent.5269
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.33 53166 192.168.1.21 22`

Comment: @PeterPeterson Can you set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` (introduced here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474220/6309) to `ssh -v` in order to see what is going on?

Comment: GIT_SSH_COMMAND is not set, `echo $GIT_EXEC_PATH/
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core/`

Comment: I meant, on Ubuntu: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v' git ls-remote INTRANET:/c/Users/git/myrepo.git`

Comment: `debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack '/c/Users/git/myrepo.git'
fatal: ''/c/Users/git/myrepo.git'' does not appear to be a git repository
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2712, received 2972 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 15241.3, received 16702.4
debug1: Exit status 128
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: @PeterPeterson Strange the path should be correct (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39593539/6309). What happens if you open a bash session on Windows, and type `git ls-remote /c/Users/git/myrepo.git` (assuming that `dir c:\Users\git\myrepo.git` does work)

Comment: everything seems OK `$ git ls-remote /c/Users/git/myrepo.git/
2bd71e2bf025d992ec3ceba1bfd398fa69b1a0e7        HEAD
2bd71e2bf025d992ec3ceba1bfd398fa69b1a0e7        refs/heads/master`

Comment: @PeterPeterson Mmm... that looks like https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/400

Comment: RIGHT; "Looks like if I do not mention any protocol, git is picking up ssh and cloning works fine"

Comment: @PeterPeterson the scp-like syntax is indeed an SSH one (xxx:yyy)