# Git Bash on windows is stuck in some kind of linux shell environment

Tags: git, bash

Usually I start it up and I'm located in my windows user directory. I can see all my project folders with a quick `ll`. The last few times I've used it, though, I seem to be stuck in some pseudo linux environment. `pwd` says I'm at `/`. And if I `cd ..` I go nowhere.

And none of the folders look like I'm on windows. What is going on here?

```
Buttle@butkus MINGW64 /
$ ll
total 3412
drwxr-xr-x 1 Buttle 197609       0 Oct 29 14:13 bin/
drwxr-xr-x 1 Buttle 197609       0 Oct 29 14:13 cmd/
drwxr-xr-x 1 Buttle 197609       0 Oct 29 14:13 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 1 Buttle 197609       0 Oct 29 14:13 etc/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Buttle 197609  140800 Oct 19 20:06 git-bash.exe*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Buttle 197609  140288 Oct 19 20:06 git-cmd.exe*
drwxr-xr-x 1 Buttle 197609       0 Oct 29 14:13 mingw64/
dr-xr-xr-x 9 Buttle 197609       0 Feb  2 01:35 proc/
-rw-r--r-- 1 Buttle 197609   57831 Oct 19 20:17 ReleaseNotes.html
drwxr-xr-x 1 Buttle 197609       0 Feb  2 01:35 tmp/
-rw-r--r-- 1 Buttle 197609  968936 Oct 29 14:13 unins000.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Buttle 197609 1300779 Oct 29 14:09 unins000.exe*
drwxr-xr-x 1 Buttle 197609       0 Oct 29 14:13 usr/

Buttle@butkus MINGW64 /
$
```

As stated above, I'm using Windows. But the reason I'm confused is that I used to start out inside my regular Windows filesystem's user directory, from which I could just cd into the project directory. Now I don't know where I am. `pwd` says I'm in the root directory but I cannot find any of my Windows filesystem or any of my git projects. Git UI for Windows (again, on Windows) is working fine but I prefer the command line.

Edit:
Notes on solutions

Thanks to @Tim Biegeleisen for his answer. I also found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10652224/631764

I edited the original Git Bash shortcut in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Git` and removed --cd-to-home from the start up options. Then I changed the "Start in" section to go to my projects directory, so that it now looks like this: `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Projects`

I had to delete my Taskbar icon - it had somehow gotten disconnected from its roots - and then after pinning the Git Bash shortcut to my taskbar, everything worked as expected. If it becomes disconnected again, I will just delete and restore the Taskbar pin again.

Comment: Vaguely Unix-like, yes, but that's hardly "some kind of Linux". Linux is "some kind of Unix", not the other way around.

Comment: Can you expand on what you're using? This looks like the git-for-windows SDK / msys2. All provide an environment to *nix programs to operate in, and that includes a ~virtual filesystem which you're seeing here. Normally some paths are mapped to real locations on your NTFS filesystem, but I only really know cygwin (which maps at /cygdrive). If the paths are somehow inaccessible, it's likely it will just fallback to the root for the default working directory.

Comment: This is what it's supposed to look like. Those directories you see will be under wherever you installed Git Bash to.

Comment: @M.M Well that's strange that it's supposed to look like a black box from which I cannot escape, in which no repositories may be found, because it never looked like that until about a week ago. It used to put me in my Windows filesystem user directory when I started it up. Tim Biegeleisen answered got me out of this jail, but I still wonder just where I am when I launch the Git bash.

Comment: The `pwd` command shows you the full (Unix-like) path of the current directory. `cd` with no arguments should take you to your home directory. `echo $HOME` or `echo ~` will show you the full path of your home directory. It sounds like git bash may have lost track of your home directory. It sets up something that looks like a Unix directory structure, with `/` as the root. That *should* map to some specific Windows directory.

Comment: @ButtleButkus It simulates a unix-like directory structure so that common tools work which assume that structure (e.g. bash looks in /etc for stuff).  Your other drives will be mounted under their drive letter , e.g. `cd /c` . Previously you would have been under `/c` somewhere but not noticed.

Comment: @M.M yes I didn't notice anything Unix-y in my directory structure before. Of course I was surprised and happy I could use `ll` and other familiar command line tools. I guess I could even add my own aliases to `etc/bash.bashrc`. But I wonder if I am actually traversing directories in my Windows computer or if it is just simulated? It seems like the place I'm starting now, with the Unix-y stuff, is completely disconnected from my simulated Windows directories in this git bash interface.

Comment: Yes, they  are real directories under your Git Bash installation somewhere

Comment: @M.M but yet I cannot `cd ..` in my git bash interface to descend out of them. That's my confusion. It's like I'm stuck there. Except `cd /C` does take me out to my regular windows C drive.

Comment: Yes, as I said earlier the purpose is to simulate a unix-like structure. You can't `cd ..` from root in that either. Read up on *mounting* in filesystems,  that path is mounted on `/`.

Answer (score 6):

From what I can, this is normal behavior for the Git Bash tool.  I was able to reproduce the Linux-esque directory listing obtained by typing `ll`.  The reason `pwd` is returning `/` is because your bash is starting up in the root directory, which defaults to the location where Git was installed on your machine (`C:\Program Files\Git` on my computer).  When you type `cd ..` you can't go anywhere, because you are already in the root position in the directory tree.

To change to your user directory you can try the following:

```
tbiegeleisen@niihau MINGW64 /
$ cd C:

tbiegeleisen@niihau MINGW64 /c
$ cd Users/tbiegeleisen/
```

I think the only difference in behavior you are seeing is that the Git bash may have someone "forgotten" in which directory it should start.  If you use the two commands I gave above, you can easily navigate back to the directory containing your source code.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why it didn't occur to me to type the full path to where I was going. But I still find it strange that I seemed to be inside of a jailed shell. It does seem like it "forgot" where it should start. I should like to remind it. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Let me research this and get back to you.