# How to change a starting folder in git-bash?

Tags: git-bash

I would like to ask you guys how to change the starting folder in git-bash? I tried to paste the path in "start in" in the properties but somehow it does not work.
Thanks

Comment: "In Git"? Do you mean the Git Bash terminal in Windows?

Comment: What do you mean? How are you using git?

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific. For what reason are you trying to share a folder and with whom? What properties were you looking at?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671461/how-do-i-change-the-default-location-for-git-bash-on-windows

Comment: Apologies I should be more specific. I pinned git bash to my taskbar and when I click it it starts in the default git folder but I want it to start it in my project folder. I checked one of the answers in the "Possible duplicate" comment. I created .bashrc file and added this line
cd \D:\Programming\php_and_laravel\php_code_examples;
It returns the message that this directory does not exist.

Comment: Sorted, I forgot to change backslashes for forward slashes in the .bashrc file in the path to my project folder

Comment: You might want to update your question as it doesn't refer to `git` but `git-bash` instead.