# Change default drive for Git Bash on Windows

Tags: shell, git-bash

Every time I launch Git Bash, it is not using my local C: drive.

How to change the launching drive for Git Bash?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the default location for Git Bash on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7671461/1072229)

Comment: I was able to fix it by setting HOME variable to the drive I wanted