# How do I always run Git Bash as an admin on Windows?

Tags: bash, git-bash, elevated-privileges

I want to run git bash on Windows as an admin, every time I open it.

My OS is Windows 10 Home 64-bit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found this result on Google:

**Set up Git Bash to always run as Administrator**

1. Click the Windows Start button and type bash.
2. Right-click the found link and select Open file location.
3. Right-click the menu shortcut and select Properties.
4. On the Compatibility tab select Run this program as administrator.

Comment: How do you make sure it still opens where you are in directory level and not at root directory level?

Comment: If you want Git to start at a different directory, this question has a lot of great answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671461/how-do-i-change-the-default-location-for-git-bash-on-windows

I don't believe there is a way to reopen at the directory you were last in..