# How to open a new git-bash tab in Windows Terminal in the same directory?

Tags: git-bash, windows-terminal

I was able to integrate git-bash in the (new) Windows10 Terminal. (This app from Microsoft's AppStore is able to host more than one console-app in one single window, organized in tabs.)

But whenever I open a new tab for git-bash, it sets the working directory to `/c/WINDOWS/system32`.

I would prefer to have the same working directory as in the tab from where I opened the new tab.
Is there a possibility for that?

Answer (score 6):

In Windows Terminal click on the arraw down button and click Settings (alternatively, press `Ctrl+Shift+,`). This will open the settings.json file. Then add `"startingDirectory": ""` to the GitBash profile. This should change the default directory to where you opened the terminal.

It should be like this:

```json
{
    "guid": "{e9961a24-1111-2222-3333-835a2d22397d}",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "Git Bash",
    "icon" : "%PROGRAMFILES%\\git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico",
    "commandline": "%PROGRAMFILES%\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe -l -i",
    "historySize" : 9001,
    "padding" : "0, 0, 0, 0",
    "snapOnInput" : true,
    "useAcrylic" : true,
    "startingDirectory": "~",
    "acrylicOpacity": 0.9          
}
```

Notes:

- `"startingDirectory": "~"` in this config makes Git Bash start in the user profile directory.
- You can replace `e9961a24-1111-2222-3333-835a2d22397d` with any other unique UUID.

Comment: Funny thing that it (~ sign) was working for me for a long time, and recently I started seeing: [error 0x8007010b when launching `%PROGRAMFILES%/Git/bin/bash.exe --login -i -l']
Could not access starting directory "C:\WINDOWS\system32\~"
Once changed to empty is working fine, but does not open user profile directory.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `"startingDirectory": "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"` setting works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As [noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58599275/6309), check if your `.bashrc` has any `cd` directive.
And check first if said `.bashrc` is called at all when opening a new git bash tab in [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal): add an echo in said `%USERPROFILE%\.bashrc`.

But this issue might not be limited to git bash.
See if [`microsoft/terminal` issue 3158](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3158) applies:

> I've come with a workaround: change the starting directory.
>
> Put this function into `$PROFILE` (make sure to adjust `$path`)
>
> ```
> function sd {
>    $path = >'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json'
>     ((Get-Content -path $path) -replace '"startingDirectory":.*', ("`"startingDirectory`": `"$pwd`"") -replace "\\", "\\") | Set-Content -Path $path
> }
> ```
>
> .. and you'll be able to a open new tab in the same directory almost with no hassle, just make sure to type sd before opening a new tab.
>
> Of course, the drawback is that startingDirectory is changed every time the function is called.