# How to change Git root directory?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

When I installed git, I made a mistake to set **c:/users/jack** as the root directory. But there're many unwanted folders under **jack** . So When I open git-bash, the directory is under **jack**. And when I open git-gui, there are thousands of unrelated files in the sidebar which I can't do anything to change it. So I want to create a folder called **code** as the root directory of git. Is there any way to achieve it without uninstalling git?(btw, I'm using windows)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7671461/13126651 duplicate of this?

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, I had seen that question before I asked. I'm not that smart to get it because that's a bit different from my problem.

Comment: By the way, your link fixed another problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply delete the `c:/users/jack/.git` folder and inside your **code** folder, initialize git using `git init` command