# How can I change my GitBash default opening directory?

Tags: git-bash

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSgXK.png)
everytime I open my Gitbash it is openning in User@DESKTOP-DGJH67S MINGW64 ~/Documents/web dev prac1/JavaScript

I want to change it to somewhere else not in the "web dev parc1"
I tried all the target, start in method, reinstalled gitbash, everything ends up in the same location.

Comment: Protip: avoid spaces in paths and try to keep paths close to the root of the filesystem to avoid _ergonomic pain_ in navigating to-and-away your source code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the default location for Git Bash on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671461/how-do-i-change-the-default-location-for-git-bash-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

echo "cd '/c/yourpath'" >> ~/.bashrc